# CloudFormation Script - Referencing earlier created Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script which is working fine except I need to be able to add my EC2 security group to an RDS security group so that the EC2 instance can access the MySQL database on the RDS instance.

Here is the section which creates the EC2 security group;

```
 "WebSecurityGroup" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
   "Properties" : {
     "GroupDescription" : "SSH Access, and complete access to ports 80 & 443.",
     "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
       "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
       "FromPort" : "22",
       "ToPort" : "22",
       "CidrIp" : "My.IP.Add.Ress/32" },
       {
       "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
       "FromPort" : "80",
       "ToPort" : "80",
       "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
       {
       "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
       "FromPort" : "443",
       "ToPort" : "443",
       "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
     } ]
   }
 },
```

And here is the RDS security group, attempting to reference it;

```
 "DBSecurityGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "Access from the EC2 instance to MySQL.",
    "DBSecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
      "EC2SecurityGroupName" : { "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup" },
      "EC2SecurityGroupId" : { "Ref" : "WebSecurityGroup" }
       } ]
 }
}
```

Any input or pointers are gratefully received.

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Using EC2 classic, I've just re-run the configuration and I get the following messages;

The following resource(s) failed to create: [DBSecurityGroup].
Exactly one of CIDRIP, EC2SecurityGroupId, and EC2SecurityGroupName must be specified and not empty.

Comment: Your problem is in the error message. You are specifying both `EC2SecurityGroupName` and `EC2SecurityGroupId`. For EC2 Classic, only specify `EC2SecurityGroupName`.

Comment: OK, I had that previously but when I only define the SecurityGroupName I get the following message; ```Access Denied to API Version: API20120917```

Comment: Does your IAM user have permissions to create DB security groups?

Comment: Ok, I think that may have helped, I've just manually checked the RDS security group page and get the following message; "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console, Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms and Using RDS in VPC."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the error message. In your `AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup` resource, you are specifying both `EC2SecurityGroupName` and `EC2SecurityGroupId` for an ingress rule. For EC2 Classic, specify only `EC2SecurityGroupName`.

EDIT: New regions, such as EU Central (Frankfurt), do not support EC2-Classic. So you must put your RDS instance within a VPC. This means, you need to create a VPC security group instead of an RDS security group.